# Varnish HAproxy cookbook

Tags: chef-infra, varnish, haproxy, chef-recipe, varnish-vcl

I am trying to write HAproxy + Varnish with apache running on backend nodes.

My question is, how do I write in the cookbook to tell haproxy or varnish to check (vcl for example for varnish) If the request is to static file send it to backend nodes role webserverS, and if it's dynamic send it to role webserverD.

The reason haproxy is at the front and not varnish is because not all the content should be cached..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a VCL file defining two back-ends, and then in your `vcl_recv` set the `req.backend_hint` to the appropriate back-end based on your criteria. See [this article for more information](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/vcl-backends.html).

You can tell Varnish what to cache, and what not to cache, using VCL, so you don't need another layer on the front to achieve that. The [Varnish book](http://book.varnish-software.com/4.0/) is free and gives details.

Comment: I like your answer a lot, I have to say my experience with Varnish is limited to certain caching scenarios, so maybe I don't need to write HAProxy cookbook for simple cached loadbalanced web app but rather focus more on using all what's available from varnish, I will wait a bit and mark it answered if no other ways suggested. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks Ridah. The Varnish book is very good and will give you a good grounding for setting it up, if you decide to go that way. There are lots of useful posts on the Varnish blog and around the web too.